# WebAPI CORS doesn't work in IE10 and Firefox but not in Chrome and Safari

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, asp.net-web-api, cors

I deploy my API in a cloud service in Windows Azure. I want to allow to call my api from fron-end developers computers and We've found an error when we use IE10 and Firefox 21.0 but not with Chrome 26.0 and Safari 5.1.7.

I've attached an image error of IE10

http://sdrv.ms/111EPu9

In Safari Works fine

http://sdrv.ms/111EPu9

In my web.config for dev purposes I've added this:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV"/>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE"/>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="authenticate, accept, origin, authorization, content-type" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Any ideas/suggestions about this error?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per spec, if the response to the OPTIONS is not an HTTP/200 the loads should be aborted.  Unfortunately, WebKit (and hence Safari and Chrome) does not implement that part of the spec correctly.